# IEnumerator does not implement interface IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerator

I am unsure why I am getting the following error message:

Error   CS0540  'Tilemap.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()': containing type does not implement interface 'IEnumerable'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZo29.png)

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TileMapper
{
    class Tilemap<T>
    {

        //Tilemap implementation
        private readonly T[,] tilemap;

        public int Width { get; }
        public int Height { get; }

        public Tilemap(int width, int height)
        {
            this.Width = width;
            this.Height = height;
            this.tilemap = new T[width, height];
        }

        public T this[int x, int y]
        {
            get { return this.tilemap[x, y]; }
            set { this.tilemap[x, y] = value; }
        }

        //Tilemap as collection
        public int Count => this.Width * this.Height;

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < this.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < this.Width; x++)
                {
                    yield return this[x, y];
                }
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }

    }
}
```

I've searched for similar errors but most just reference adding the

```
 IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return this.GetEnumerator();
            }
```

which is what is giving me the error.

Comment: Look at the first line of your class definition. Tell me what interfaces it implements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class definition doesn't say it implements `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
class Tilemap<T>: IEnumerable<T>
{
     //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it, however it is "IEnumerable<T>" not "IEnumerator<T>" for anyone else that has this issue.

Comment: InBetween, I have another question. I am following this guide http://genericgamedev.com/general/writing-a-generic-tilemap-class/#comment-701 Which near the end it asked to change the inheritance to IReadOnlyCollection<Tile<T>> My current class looks like this: class Tilemap<T>: IEnumerable<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<Tile<T>> but I am getting this error: 'Tilemap<T>' does not implement interface member 'IEnumerable<Tile<T>>.GetEnumerator()' 'Tilemap<T>.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 'IEnumerable<Tile<T>>GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of IEnumerator<Tile<T>>

Comment: @ScottNeustadt You are currently implementing `IEnumerable<T>` . You probably want to implement `IEnumerable<Tile<T>>`, therefore your `GetEnumerator()` should return `IEnumerator<Tile<T>>`, not `IEnumerator<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that the class implements the interface:

```
class Tilemap<T> : IEnumerable
```